# ytd problems in sql

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, oracle10g, business-objects

If a user enters the hiredate as 02/03/2013 then it will display all the employee information **between 01/01/2013 (starting of the year) to 30/03/2013**(end of the given month).

what will be the query to extract the result.

```
empno  hiredate    name
-----------------------
01     02/03/2013  abc
02     23/07/2013  bvg
03     05/04/2013  fhdsk
04     22/08/2013  kjk
```

format is dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: It isn't exactly clear what you want to retrieve. Could you give an example? Also, is your date format mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy?

Answer (score 1):

You need to give more information, like the table schema, sample data and examples of what you want.  Your solution could be as basic as this:

```
SELECT *
FROM employee
WHERE hiredate between '01/01/2013' AND '30/03/2013';
```

Or are you expecting more than just SQL code?

---

Here is some pseudo code to help you.  Conceptually these are user defined functions with the logic shown.

```
SELECT *
FROM hiredate BETWEEN udf_BOY('02/03/2013') AND udf_EOM('02/03/2013');

udf_BOY(@date) :==
RETURN  CAST('01/01/' + DATEPART(year, @date) AS datetime)

udf_EOM(@date) :==
RETURN DATEADD(DAY, -(DAY(DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @date))), DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @date))
```

Comment: the user should input the hiredate dynamic for eg: if we give 02/03/2013 then it extract the data from strating of the year to ending of the month. so in my query it gives the o/p like whose hiredate in between 01/01/2013 to 31/03/2013